# javaのTimerクラスのscheduleメソッドについて

Tags: java

タイムアウトの実装をしたくてTimerクラスのscheduleメソッドを使い,

```
   to.schedule( time,1000 );
```

のようにして1000ms後にtimeオブジェクトの処理を実行させています.

```
class TimeOut extends TimerTask {
    private boolean isStop = false;
    public void run(){
        isStop = true;
    }
    public boolean getStop(){
        return isStop;
    }
}
```

一方でこのtimeオブジェクトの実行内容はTimerTaskを継承したTimeOutクラス内のrun()メソッドで定義されています.
これはisStop変数の中身をtrueにするだけのもので,のちに

```
if(time.getStop()==true){
      /*処理*/
}
```

のようにしてisStop変数を参照してタイムアウトされたかを判断したいと思っています.
しかしどうも1000ms後にtimeオブジェクトのrun()が実行されるとオブジェクトの中身が破棄されてしまっているようで後からisStopが参照できないようです.
こういう場合どうすればいいのでしょうか.

Comment: 過去に似たような質問に回答しています。TImerクラスを使うものではありませんがご参考までに。 http://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/13066/10492

Comment: 『オブジェクトの中身が破棄されてしまっているようで後からisStopが参照できない』というのは、具体的にどういうコードを書いた場合どんなエラーが出る(あるいはエラーは出ないが想定しない結果になる)ということでしょうか。おそらく文中の`if(time.getStop()==true)`の箇所で意図しない挙動になっているのだろう、というのは読み取れますが、何が起こっているのかが想像できません。

Comment: 弱参照を使っていないと思うので破棄されることはありません。後から「isStop」メソッドを呼び出せる状況を作っているということは参照をもっているということですから破棄されないです。「参照できないようです」の部分について、どうしてそのように思ったかを教えてください。

Answer (score 2):

`TimeOut`クラスの`run`メソッドが呼ばれていますか？
`Timer`を使う場合、通常であれば下記のように処理を呼び出すと思います。

```
final TimeOut timeOut = new TimeOut();
final Timer timer = new Timer();

System.out.println(timeOut.getStop());

timer.schedule(timeOut, 1000);
// 10秒間処理を待つ
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
timer.cancel();

System.out.println(timeOut.getStop());
```

このとき、1000ms後の処理を待たずに`Timer`クラスの`cancel`メソッドを呼び出してしまうと`TimeOut`クラスの`run`メソッドは呼び出されません。

ちなみに上記の簡易なコードであれば最初の出力は`false`、最後の出力は`true`になります。